# Como puedo comparar una fecha obtenida con sqlalchemy con la fecha actual

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

Fecha obtenida mediante sqlalchemy

```
'2019-12-24 08:07:22.584212'
```

fecha actual

```py
datetime.datetime.now()
```

Necesito compararlas mas no se como hacerlo para convertirlos al mismo formato, algo así:

```
'2019-12-24 08:07:22.584212' > datetime.datetime.now()
```

Error

> TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'datetime.datetime'

Agradeceria cualquier ayuda de su parte gracias.

Comment: No se si esta pregunta en [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49554491/not-supported-between-instances-of-datetime-date-and-str) te puede ayudar. Al fin y al cabo el error te da al intentar comparar peras con manzanas tienes que castear el string a date o viceversa

Comment: gracias si tienes razon estaba comparando peras con manzanas, buscare como parsearlos para comparar manzanas con manzanas

Comment: ¿Tienes en cuenta si es tiempo de una zona determinada o tiempo UTC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encontre una solución sencilla con la libreria dateutil

```
fecha_sqlalchemy = '2019-12-24 08:07:22.584212'
```

```py
from dateutil.parser import parse

parse(fecha_sqlalchemy) < datetime.datetime.now()

True
```

Espero le sirva a alguien más.

Gracias.